# Distinguishing between a memory leak and normal memory usage

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-management, memory-leaks, android-recyclerview

I am creating an Android app, and I've only just recently begun to examine the memory usage.

My app consists of a main activity and two fragments within (Fragment A holds a recyclerview with images, Fragment B holds an image and some text boxes).

I've noticed that when I start the app, my memory allocation is at roughly 20MB. By scrolling up and down on the recyclerview in Fragment A (not loading any new data) I can make the memory usage increase nonstop (until garbage collection).

Also, if I go from fragment A to fragment B back and forth, I can make the memory allocation increase nonstop (until garbage collection). 20 -> 23 -> 29, .. etc. Until it gets to 60+ and gets garbage collected.

If I start the app at roughly 23MB allocated, and do some scrolling and moving back and forth between fragments, my  memory usage might be somewhere between 40 and 60+ MB.

When I use Android Studio to garbage collect multiple times in a row, I can bring it back down but not all the way to 23 (usually to 30ish).

Is this a memory leak since I'm unable to garbage collect 100% of the memory I started out with?

Answer (score 0):

No, strictly speaking you can't have that kind of memory leak in java since it is garbage collected.

You'll get "leaks" in java if you are keeping a reference to something you no longer use (I.E. a big list or something that you never remove from). But keep in mind that these can always be fixed by being sure to discard references to things you don't need to keep around (removing things from lists/sets/maps, closing files ... etc). The persistent memory that you are looking at is probably from some static variables since those are bound to the classes.